# Trying to stub a method used inside a Node module

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai, stub

I'm trying to mock a function inside a Node module. But it doesn't allow me. Any ideas?

```
// module A

function foo(){
  return 1;
}

function bar(){
   return foo() + 1;
}

module.exports = {foo, bar}
```

In the test...

```
const a = require('a');
...
sinon.stub(a, 'foo').callsFake(() => 3);
expect(a.bar()).to.equal(4); // gets 2 instead of 4
```

Answer (score 5):

Due to the way Sinon stubs a function in a module you actually end up with an interesting situation.  Your function is actually being stubbed but is being stubbed only at `module.exports.foo`.  Your original function `foo` is unchanged.  Basically what Sinon does is that it wraps your `module.exports.{function}` with their special functionalities.

If you want to have any stubs persist in your `bar` function you need to reference `foo` on the exports object and not directly.

```
function bar() {
  return module.exports.foo() + 1;
}
```

Good luck :)

**EDIT**: Usually when I want to do things like this I write my modules and use their functions this way...

```
// module A

exports.foo = function foo() {
  return 1;
}

exports.bar = function bar() {
  return exports.foo() + 1;
}
```

That way if anything in the module gets stubbed / mocked / spied it will apply to all other calls inside of the module.  But in general my recommendation is if you plan to ever plan to stub a function you never want to reference it directly from anywhere.  You need to reference those functions through an object so that Sinon can perform the replacement on the object.

Comment: No worries!  I added an alternative that you can try in your module.  I find that always works for me when I need to stub out functions in a module.